# What value of feature in method startUsingNetworkFeature(int networkType, String feature) is valid

Tags: android

- In the class **ConnectivityManager**, I see a method as belows:

  - public int **startUsingNetworkFeature**(int **networkType**, String **feature**)
  - In my opinion:
  - **networkType** = TYPE_MOBILE or TYPE_WIFI or TYPE_MOBILE_MMS or TYPE_MOBILE_SUPL or TYPE_MOBILE_DUN or TYPE_MOBILE_HIPRI
  - **feature = ?**
  - Please help me to answer the question "***what value of feature is valid***".
  - Thanks & best regards,
  - DaiSon

Answer (score 3):

"enableMMS"
"enableSUPL"
"enableDUN"
"enableHIPRI"

Found in http://www.sephidev.net/frameworks/base/telephony/java/com/android/internal/telephony/Phone.java from values of FEATURE_ENABLE_MMS, ...., FEATURE_ENABLE_HIPRI

Encontrado en (link de arriba) de los valores de FEATURE_ENABLE_MMS, ...., FEATURE_ENABLE_HIPRI

Comment: The one that work to me was "enableSUPL" 
connmanager.startUsingNetworkFeature(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE,"enableSUPL")

Answer (score 0):

More about first argument you can read in documentation to ConnectivityManager. List of available features you can found in internal interface Phone:

```
 // "Features" accessible through the connectivity manager  
   static final String FEATURE_ENABLE_MMS = "enableMMS";  
   static final String FEATURE_ENABLE_SUPL = "enableSUPL";  
   static final String FEATURE_ENABLE_DUN = "enableDUN";  
   static final String FEATURE_ENABLE_HIPRI = "enableHIPRI";  
   static final String FEATURE_ENABLE_DUN_ALWAYS = "enableDUNAlways";  
   static final String FEATURE_ENABLE_FOTA = "enableFOTA";  
   static final String FEATURE_ENABLE_IMS = "enableIMS";  
   static final String FEATURE_ENABLE_CBS = "enableCBS";
```

Found this information here :http://vnamashko.blogspot.com/2012/05/deep-look-at-android-networking-part-3.html